# PERL LibXML Parser

Tags: xml, perl, xml-libxml

I am having following XML which I required to process

```
  <table>
    <col1>check1</col1>
    <col2>check2</col2>
    <col3>check3</col3>
    <content>
        <data>gt1</data>
        <data>check_gt1</data>
    </content>
    <content>
        <data>gt2</data>
        <data>check_gt2</data>
    </content>
</table>
```

I wrote the following code to process this XML

```
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $respDom = $parser->parse_string($xmldata);
my @rowNodes = $respDom->getDocumentElement->findnodes("//content");

if(scalar @rowNodes > 0) 
{
    print "\nRow nodes size is ".scalar @rowNodes."\n"; 
    foreach my $rowNode (@rowNodes) {
          my $colNode = $rowNode->findnodes("//data")->[0];           
          my $num = $colNode->textContent;

          print "\nNUM is ".$colNode;
    }
}
```

My result showing the size of node "content" is 2. But it returns "gt1" two times inside the loop, It is not returning "gt2" in the second iteration.

Is there anything I need to change on this ?

Comment: The `*` in `//content` is making the code return 0 `@rowNodes` for me. With `//content` it gives the behaviour you are describing. Please fix that in the question.

Comment: thanks. Fixed the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPath expression for finding the `data` node is wrong. An XPath with `//foo` will search any element with that name. It searches in the whole document tree, not only below that node. And with your `->[0]` it will always return the first match, which is `gt1` for the full document.

**Remove the slashes.**

```
my $colNode = $rowNode->findnodes("data")->[0];
```

---

To check that `$rowNode` actually contains the full document tree, but only points to the current node, try this:

```
my $colNode = $rowNode->findnodes("../content/data")->[0];
```

It will also give you `gt1` twice.

Comment: Thanks for your response. You saved my day.

Comment: Is there any possible way to get the xml as string under the "content"->[0] tag ?

Comment: @Aravind you should ask a new question for that.

Comment: I have added as new question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34744470/getting-full-xml-string-from-perl-libxml-parser