# Getting full XML string from PERL LibXML Parser

Tags: xml, perl, libxml2

I am having following XML which I required to process

```
<table>
<col1>check1</col1>
<col2>check2</col2>
<col3>check3</col3>
<content>
    <data>gt1</data>
    <data>check_gt1</data>
</content>
</table>
```

I want to get "`<content><data>gt1</data><data>check_gt1</data></content>`" from the parser.

My parsing code is as follows,

```
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $respDom = $parser->parse_string($xmldata);
print "content is ".$respDom->getDocumentElement->findnodes("//content");
```

The above code results in the textContent inside the nodes.How can I get the data I mentioned above ?

Comment: Note that you can call `findnodes` directly on the document node: `$respDom->findnodes("//content")`

Comment: Thanks, Is there any possible way to get only "<data>gt1</data><data>check_gt1</data>" in perl without doing the parsing ?

Answer (score 5):

The XML::LibXML::Node objects have [a method `toString`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/lib/XML/LibXML/Node.pod#toString). That's what you need. I found it with a quick search of the XML::LibXML documentation.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;

my $xmldata = <<'XML';
<table>
<col1>check1</col1>
<col2>check2</col2>
<col3>check3</col3>
<content>
    <data>gt1</data>
    <data>check_gt1</data>
</content>
</table>
XML

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $respDom = $parser->parse_string($xmldata);
print "content is "
  . $respDom->getDocumentElement->findnodes("//content")->[0]->toString;
```

This will print:

```
content is <content>
    <data>gt1</data>
    <data>check_gt1</data>
</content>
```

---

In general, I always search for either `to_string`, `as_string`, `stringify` or simply `string` if I need something like that and am not sure how that works in a specific module. It's almost always one of those.

---

**Update**

To only get the inside XML of the `<content>` element, you have to grab its child nodes and do `toString` for each of them. The `map` whole thing needs to be called in *list context*, or it will throw an error. Note how I changed the `.` to a `,` in the `print` statement.

```
print "content is "
  , $respDom->getDocumentElement->findnodes("//content")->[0]->childNodes->map(sub {$_->toString});
```

Comment: Note that `toString` on a non-document node produces text that's not encoded.

Comment: Is there any possible way to get only "<data>gt1</data><data>check_gt1</data>" in perl without doing the parsing ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand @Aravind.

Comment: From the above answer it provided "<content><data>gt1</data><data>check_gt1</data></content>" as result. Is it possible to get "<data>gt1</data><data>check_gt1</data>" as result(Without the element content)?

Comment: @Aravind have you looked at the documentation I linked at all?